# Control access to media files in codeigniter only for users

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new to the Codeigniter.

I have some audio files (for sale) that should be accessible to the logged-in users with the `<audio>` tag in site's `views`.

Where do I put these files, so that there is no direct access to the files? (for example with the open link in browser) But accessible for logged-in users in `views`.

application folder? or root? or... Which folder and How?

Comment: outside of the scope from your `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @sintakonte your mean is out of `public_html`  folder?

Comment: yes thats what i mean, and you access it only from a php script ...